# Replace doesn't return expected output within Table

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

```
FirstList = {{1, 2, x}, {2, 3, x}, {4, 2, x}, {x, 3, 5}, {x, 7, 8}};
SecondList = {a, b, c, d, e};
Table[
  Replace[Part[FirstList, n], x -> Part[SecondList, n]], {n, Length[SecondList]}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, x}, {2, 3, x}, {4, 2, x}, {x, 3, 5}, {x, 7, 8}}
> ```

I expected the output to be

> ```
> {{1, 2, a}, {2, 3, b}, {4, 2, c}, {d, 3, 5}, {e, 7, 8}}
> ```

How do you make it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The level specification of `Replace` is wrong. Compare:

```
Replace[x, x -> a]
Replace[{1, 2, x}, x -> a]
Replace[{1, 2, x}, x -> a, {1}]

Out[14]= a

Out[15]= {1, 2, x}

Out[16]= {1, 2, a}
```

So to make this work, add a level specification to `Replace`:

```
Table[Replace[Part[FirstList, n], x -> Part[SecondList, n], {1}], {n, Length[SecondList]}]
```

You can also use `ReplaceAll`, which operates at every level. In general, though, I prefer `Replace` where possible over the scattershot approach of `ReplaceAll`.

Answer (score 2):

`ReplaceAll` (operator form: `/.`) automatically moves through all levels, so in this case it will do its replacements at level 1 and give the result you want.

```
a1 = {{1, 2, x}, {2, 3, x}, {4, 2, x}, {x, 3, 5}, {x, 7, 8}};
a2 = {a, b, c, d, e};
MapThread[(#1 /. x -> #2) &, {a1, a2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, a}, {2, 3, b}, {4, 2, c}, {d, 3, 5}, {e, 7, 8}}
> ```

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to say "`ReplaceAll` works at level 1 by default", because `ReplaceAll` does not have a level spec and works on every level (not just level 1).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit. Good point. I should have written "starts at". I have made this correction.

Comment: But `ReplaceAll ` also works at level 0... Or am I confusing level specs with positions here?

Comment: To clarify: compare `Replace[x, x -> 1, {0}]` with `ReplaceAll[x, x -> 1]`. Both do the replacement, which happens at level 0.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit. You're right. I seem to be having one of my muddle headed days. I think I've got the wording right this time. But if you think not, please keep working on putting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = {{1, 2, x}, {2, 3, x}, {4, 2, x}, {x, 3, 5}, {x, 7, 8}};

a2 = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[a2 &, a1, Position[a1, x]]
```

{{1, 2, a}, {2, 3, b}, {4, 2, c}, {d, 3, 5}, {e, 7, 8}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = {{1, 2, x}, {2, 3, x}, {4, 2, x}, {x, 3, 5}, {x, 7, 8}};

a2 = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[a1, Thread[Position[a1, x] -> #] &@a2]

(*{{1, 2, a}, {2, 3, b}, {4, 2, c}, {d, 3, 5}, {e, 7, 8}}*)
```